# Short story, older people who can't separate mind from body

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Possibly set in Cambridge, true self and form self.  An older or aged woman is unable to separate her mind -- true self -- from her body -- form self. Younger people can apparently do this at will, and there is some reason why these older people have to be taken care of or watched carefully. I read this maybe 25-30 years ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question is very terse.  There's almost nothing here to go on.  Please check out the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any other details you can [edit] into your question.  When and where did you read it?

Comment: Cambridge, England? Cambridge, Massachusetts? Cambridge, Ontario? Some other Cambridge?

Comment: From what is told, I can only think of *His Dark Materials* by Phillip Pullman. The first book is set in an alternative world Oxford, in which people have their soul under the form of animals, called *daemons*. The daemons of the youngs still change of form until they reach the age of what they know what they're going to be, and the form stays until they die. The story of the first book revolves around the fact of adult wanting to separate children from their daemons to get the *dust*.

Comment: The story may have been set in Cambridge England. It's been a very long time since I read it, my apologies for having so little information about it.

Comment: Did people have to walk to separate their mind from their body? Specifically, if somebody tied your legs together, would that prevent the process of freeing your mind from your body?

Comment: I don't think people had to walk to separate mind from body, but that's an interesting idea! Is there a story with that as the plot?

Comment: Unready to Wear by Kurt Vonnegut, Jr. had the plot where people could take a few steps and separate themselves from their bodies. It was in the April 1953 issue of Galaxy Magazine, and has been in a bunch of anthologies.